# Is there a way to know what kind of outcome I will get from a situation?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Say I decide to take a drone part, as an option in an event. The wiki tells me that there are 2 possible outcomes:

- I will receive a drone part and scrap
- I will lose a crew member but get some scrap

Is there any way to find out what outcome I will receive? If I, say, have upgraded engines, will one outcome be more common than the other?

Comment: It's random at the time of choosing, so there's no way to know ahead of time. I don't know either way whether your ship's equipment can alter the probabilities though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, there's no in-game way of knowing what the odds of a particular outcome are.

Having particular ship parts can unlock *additional* choices in some events. (These choices are labeled in blue.) The chance of a regular (white text) choice having a positive outcome  is always the same regardless of the circumstances.

For example, having upgraded engines can unlock a special (blue) choice in some events, but it will never affect the odds of the regular (white) choices.

I'm pretty sure (but not 100%; please correct me if I'm wrong in the comments) that the  special choices will always have a positive result, so if they're available to you, be sure to select them.

Comment: The Blue Choices aren't all unqualifiedly better; most are, and some are merely less risky. To use your example, you could get ambushed, but your engines will allow you to escape - or you could fight it out, and loot their ship for fun and profit.

One of the important things about Blue Choices is that they're (in almost all cases) necessary to unlock new ship hulls.